# cannot access svn://localhost on mac

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion, svnserve

I started my SVN Server on mac using `svnserve -d` (in deamon mode) but when I access the repositories via `svn://localhost` or `svn://192.168.0.1`, it does not work.

I have setup my repository in `/Projects/SVNRepostiries/MyProject`

I have tried adding full path to the above but still does not work. If I use

```
http://localhost (note the http not svn)
```

it prompts for username and password and it does not accept my svn username and password. What possibly could cause this. I am using Mountain Lion.

Comment: What error are you getting, saying it doesn't work doesn't help much with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Safari cannot open the specified address. OSX does not recognize address starting with svn. In Firefox, similar message that says SVN isn't associated with any program.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access svnserve with a web browser.  You have to use a Subversion client to do that.

If you want to be able to access your repository with a web browser you have two choices.

- [Setup Apache httpd with mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)
- Setup a web interface like [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org/) or [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  There are actually quite a few of these.

The Apache httpd setup will let you retrieve files and minimally navigate around the head of the repository.  You can also specify the peg revision with `?p=$REV` where $REV is the revision you want to view.  You won't be able to say call up diffs or see log messages with a web browser.

If you want to get that sort of functionality you'll need to use a Subversion client or setup a web interface.

Comment: Btw I am using SmartSVN (that's where my problem started) where I can't find any repository under `svn://localhost`

Comment: @Nick Unless you give a root via the `-r` option svnserve will be rooted at the root of your system.  So you'll have to use `svn://localhost/Proejocts/SVNRepositories/MyProject`.  One thing I'll note is that Respositories is mispelled in your post above, if that's not intentional that may be behind your problem.  Again posting the exact error you're getting (or a screenshot of it) will help diagnose things better.  Be complete in describing what you've tried.